# Add horizontal padding to TextEditor but prevent it from shifting scrollbar inside as a result

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, text-editor

I'm using a TextEditor that I'd like to include horizontal padding for, so that the text doesn't stick to either edge. However, the problem is if I include it, and the text within is scrollable, then the scrollbar is not positioned to the far-right, but has instead been moved inside by the padding amount.

```
        TextEditor(text: $text)
         .background(Color.white)
         .foregroundColor(Color.black)
         .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
         .customFont(.body)
         .lineSpacing(8)
         .padding(.leading)
         .padding(.trailing)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You added padding to external frame, but need to indent internal text container. The possible solution (as TextEditor is actually UITextView) to use appearance. So the solution would be to add the following in parent view of `TextEditor`

```
init() {
    UITextView.appearance().textContainerInset = 
         UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12)   // << !!
}

// ... other code

    TextEditor(text: $text)
     .background(Color.white)
     .foregroundColor(Color.black)
     .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
     .customFont(.body)
     .lineSpacing(8)
```

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: how to do the same for macOS?

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 17+, you can use the [contentMargins](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentmargins(_:for:)?changes=_4) view modifier to achieve this. There are a few familiar overloads that support customizing the amount and position of the margins, as well as a parameter to indicate whether the margins should be applied to the TextEditor/ScrollView's contents or scroll indicators.

```swift
TextEditor(text: $text)
    .contentMargins(.horizontal, 20.0)
```