# How to put padding in a text editor so that text isn't directly on the edges(swiftUI)?

Tags: swiftui, padding

I am using a TextEditor and do not want the text to be directly touching the left side. I want it to look like most notes or document apps where the text is not crunched up on the top or sides. [image]

I tried to use a padding (as seen in the photo), but it shifted the actual TextEditor itself and not the text inside the editor. How can I pad the text but not the editor?

```
ZStack (alignment: .leading){
            
            if test.isEmpty{
                VStack{
                   
                    Text("Write something....")
                        .padding(.top)
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                        .opacity(0.6)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Spacer()
                }
            } else{
                VStack{
                    Text("")
                }
            }
            
            VStack{
                TextEditor(text: $note.text)
                    .padding()
                    .opacity(note.text.isEmpty ? 0.85 : 1)
                    .font(.custom("SanFrancisco", fixedSize: 20))
                    .onReceive(note.publisher(for: \.text), perform: setName)
                    .onReceive(
                        note.publisher(for: \.text)
                            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                            .removeDuplicates()
                    ){ _ in
                        try? PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
                    }
                    .navigationTitle(note.name)
            }
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add horizontal padding to TextEditor but prevent it from shifting scrollbar inside as a result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591082/add-horizontal-padding-to-texteditor-but-prevent-it-from-shifting-scrollbar-insi)

Comment: I don't know how to make the initializer solution work for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (iOS 16+)

```
 ZStack {
    TextEditor(text: $text)
    .padding()
  }
  .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
  .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
  .cornerRadius(15)
```